# "\xC2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run a Ruby on Rails application on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. I have successfully started the Rails server, but when I open it in my browser as `localhost:3000`, it shows me the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError in PagesController#index

"\xC2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
Rails.root: /home/tarun/tarun-webapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21:in `jammit'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

**Here is index method of `pages_controller.rb`**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
        layout false

  def index
        @user_session = UserSession.new
        @user = User.new
    if current_user
      redirect_to user_root_url
    end
  end
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "ASCII-8BIT"? ASCII itself is a 7-bit encoding, and there are multiple 8-bit "extensions" to ASCII.

Comment: This error could happen when some `.rb` file has special character like `ã, ç, ...`. To use special characters in Ruby files add `#encoding: UTF-8` on first line of file

Comment: @JonSkeet ASCII-8BIT is a Ruby thing: “`Encoding::ASCII_8BIT` is a special encoding that is usually used for a byte string, not a character string. But as the name insists, its characters in the range of ASCII are considered as ASCII characters. This is useful when you use ASCII-8BIT characters with other ASCII compatible characters.” –from http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Encoding.html

Comment: @matt: It sounds like it shouldn't be used for converting to UTF-8 then - what does a value of 0xC2 in ASCII-8BIT mean in UTF-8? (Fundamentally this is why I dislike the way some languages treat text and binary data as interchangable. It's not.)

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `PostController#index` method, and the full stacktrace?

Comment: @JonSkeet It shouldn’t be used here, it looks like the string in question is wrongly labelled as `ASCII-8BIT` when it should probably be UTF-8 (or whatever, I’m guessing UTF-8 from `C2`). Ruby is certainly guilty of conflating binary data and text.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely LANG=C or locale is unset.

Can also try something like `this_should_be_a_unicode_string = this_should_be_a_unicode_string.force_encoding('UTF-8')`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Encoding.html